laravel inertia invoking the update handeler not working (with file upload)
i dont think this is a good title but imma explain my situation
im using laravel with inertia, everything works fine ive never had such experiance with a framework
im building a quick demo to learn this stack and made a good progress in my first day
the situation, i have a post model (title, content) where each user has many posts, each post has one image, i have my resource route set up
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class)->middleware(['auth']);

everything works fine except updating a post, when updating the title and content it works, but when updating the image i got validation error for the title and content which is weird
 public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        $data = $request->only('title', 'content');

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            if ($post->image_path) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($post->image_path);
            }
            $data['image_path'] = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
        }

        $post->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post);
    }

in the client side im submitting the form using inertia's useform hook
 const { data, setData, put, processing, errors } = useForm({
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content,
        image: null,
    });

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        put(route("posts.update", post));
    };

tried using patch instead of put (not working)
i tried using forceFormData (not working)
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        put(route("posts.update", post), {forceFormData : true});
    };

i tried using form data (not working)
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("title", data.title);
        formData.append("content", data.content);
        if (data.image) {
            formData.append("image", data.image);
        }
        patch(route("posts.update", post.id), { forceFormData: true });
    };

note : i made sure the data (from useForm) has the correct data (title, content and image) and the issue isnt in collecting data from the client, also im new to laravel and php and this may sound stupid but i didnt find a way to print/echo the comming data to the server so i can make sure its the correct data im expecting

I have posted my answer with detailed explanation. Please check and let me know.


everything works fine except updating a post, when updating the title and content it works, but when updating the image i got validation error for the title and content which is weird

It is quite obvious as per the code you have written. Because you have for force validation to these fields i.e. title & content. So when you update only the image field by default you get validation error for the title and content which is not weird at all.
In order to update any of the fields independently and avoid validation issues , use sometimes that apply validation rules only when the field is present in the request like this.
$request->validate([
            'title' => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'sometimes|required|string',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

Try this it will work for sure if your image-uploading code & storage:link path properly initiated.
To know in details about sometimes validation rule you can check the link given below.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#validating-when-present

both title and content are required, but i do send them with the image (both are sent always)
i made ur changes and now i dont have any validation error
but the image is not updating (always having the previous image and its not updating)

Okay. Does the image filepath updated or not ? or both filepath and image is not updated at all?

@MouayedKeziz,  what is your image storage path and did you create symbolic link using php artisan storage:link ?

@MouayedKeziz , You can also check whether image-data is coming from the update request properly by doing dd($request->hasFile('image')). If it returns false then image data is not uploading.

yes i did use php artisan storage:link and i got the create post method working, even display the image associated with each post, after tryingdd($request->hasFile('image')) it outputs false :(

i thing the issue is related to the form data now, if i update title or content or both it works, but when the image is envolved, nothing is being updated, neither the image not the title and content

Yes you are right.How did you send image-data using FormData.How did you get this data.image ?

the three ways i mentioned in the post above, none is workin

You can check this link to know how to send file-data using FormData.
https://medium.com/@mohammedaziz_14594/sending-files-to-the-server-using-formdata-in-javascript-c2a4ed8fc85f#:~:text=key(key%20of%20the%20formData,the%20first%20file%20via%20req.
You need to send file data in this way
const fileInput = document.getElementById('test');
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
This is just an example .You can adjust in your code accordingly.

this is a famous problem, where its noticed that form data dont go along with put, patch requests, so u have to find something as a turn around, mine was creating a route with method:post to handle the update (same updatet code) with this
Route::post("posts/{post}/update", [PostController::class, "postupdate"])->middleware(['auth'])->name("posts.update");


Here are 3 solutions:


const { data, setData, post, errors, processing } = useForm({
    title: currentPost.title,
    body: currentPost.body,
    image: null,
  });

  const errorsActive = errors;

  const route = useRoute();

  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Option 1, needs a post route in web.php
    // post(route("posts.update", currentPost.id));

    // Option 2, needs a post route in web.php
    // post(`/posts/${currentPost.id}`);
    
    // Option 3
    router.post(route("posts.update", currentPost.id), {
      _method: "PUT",
      title: data.title,
      body: data.body,
      image: data.image,
    });
  }



